# I want to create a copy of a method to another variable, & alter its some properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, methods, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

```
const addVendorVallidation = async(req, res, next) => {
    let servicesRemoteData = {
        table: 'services_list',
        field: 'id',
        entity: 'services',
        type: 'ids_exists',
        isNullAllowed: false,
        model: Services,
    };

    let clientRemoteData = {
        table: 'clients_mst',
        field: 'id',
        entity: 'clients',
        type: 'ids_exists',
        isNullAllowed: true,
        model: Clients
    };
    let clientExists = await remoteChecks(clientRemoteData, req.body.client_id, res, next).then((res) => res).catch((err) => err);
    let serviceExists = await remoteChecks(servicesRemoteData, req.body.services, res, next).then((res) => res).catch((err) => err);
    const addVendorValidationSchema = joi.object({
        name: joi.string().min(4).required(),
        contact_person: joi.string().min(4).required(),
        phone: joi.number().required(),
        status: joi.optional(),
        address_line_1: joi.string().min(6).required(),
        address_line_2: joi.string(),
        country: joi.string().valid('us', 'in').required(),
        state: joi.string().min(6).required(),
        postal_code: joi.string().min(6).required(),
        city: joi.string().min(6).required(),
        client_id: joi.optional().allow(''),
        role_id: joi.number().min(1),
        user_id: joi.number().min(1),
        panel: joi.string(),
        services: joi.string().required(),
    });
    if (clientExists && serviceExists) {
        try {
            const data = req.body;
            await addVendorValidationSchema.validateAsync(data);
        } catch (err) {
            let message = (((err.details != undefined) && (err.details[0].message != undefined)) ? err.details[0].message : err);
            return res.status(422).json({
                success: false,
                message: message,
                data: []
            });
        }
        next();
    }
}
```

I have this method. I want to create new method with same definition with just some alteration. For example, in this method we have `addVendorValidationSchema` variable, I want to update some of it's values in my method. I have heard about prototypes, but not sure about it. What can be the best solution ? How can I do that ?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for help with.  Just copy the code for `addVendorValidationSchema()`, assign the copy to a different variable name and then modify the parts you want to modify.  `addVendorValidationSchema()` is just a plain function, not a method so it has nothing to do with prototypes.

Comment: @jfriend00 I can do what you said, but that is not something what I am thinking to do. I don't want to write the same things again.

Comment: @jfriend00 There would ne definitely something which could make this thing reusable.

Comment: Then figure out exactly which parts of the code you want to vary from one call to the next and make a function where you can pass the varying parts into the function as function arguments.  This is called "factoring" common functionality into a resuable function.  You haven't given us any specifics about exactly what parameters you want to vary so we can't offer you specific code.

Comment: @jfriend00 ```addVendorValidationSchema``` I want to append this variable with  ```id: joi.number().required()``` this and this line -
```let idExists = await remoteChecks(idRemoteData, req.body.id, res, next).then((res) => res).catch((err) => err);```